# TO customize the color of UITabBar in Xcode

Tags: ios4, uitabbarcontroller

Hi Could you please let me know how to change the default colour of a tababar in Xcode i hav already tried this :

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UITabBar.png"]];
  img.frame = CGRectOffset(img.frame, 0, 1);
  [tabBar1 insertSubview:img atIndex:0];
  [img release];

  but it doesnt work for me so can you please tel me in detail how can i change the colo

Answer (score 0):

I know, this is an old thread, but nonetheless for all of you looking for an answer.

One of the ways to customize the look of UITabBar is to override `drawRect:` method with use of categories. Choose to create new file in your Xcode project, choose **Objective-C category**, then type UITabBar for **Category On** textfield. Next, declare `drawRect:` method in your category .h file and implement it in category .m file like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *img  = [UIImage imageNamed: @"tabbarBackground"];
    [img drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
```

This will change the looks of all UITabBar instances in your app.

Hope this helps.